# How to convert dots to numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a text file with format

```
2..4..6.7
.1.2.3.5.
34.7..89.
```

Desired output:

```
A = 3x9 cell
 1x9 double: 200400607
 1x9 double: 010203040
 1x9 double: 340700890
```

I can read the file like this

```
importdata('inputname.txt')
```

but then they are still arrays of type char and not of type double.

How do I replace chars with numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `importdata` option that you had before:

```
data = importdata('inputname.txt');
```

Now, you can just replace all of the `.` characters with `0` via string operations.  Use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to do that:

```
data = strrep(data, '.', '0');
```

We get:

```
data = 

    '200400607'
    '010203050'
    '340700890'
```

Some older versions of MATLAB don't have `strrep`.  If you don't, then use regular expressions via [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to do that for you:

```
data = regexprep(data, '\.', '0');
```

Now, the last task is to convert each of the cells into individual digits, you can use `cellfun` and loop over each cell, and subtract each character array by the ASCII code of `0` to get your desired numeric array.  This will be type converted to a `double` array and by subtracting the ASCII code of `0`, you will get digits between 0 and 9:

```
data = cellfun(@(x) x - '0', data, 'uni', 0);
```

We get:

```
>> celldisp(data)

data{1} =

     2     0     0     4     0     0     6     0     7



data{2} =

     0     1     0     2     0     3     0     5     0



data{3} =

     3     4     0     7     0     0     8     9     0
```

However, if you want the actual full number itself rather than splitting it up into characters, just use [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) instead:

```
data = cellfun(@str2double, data);
```

You would get:

```
>> data

data =

   200400607
    10203050
   340700890
```

Take note that the above will remove any leading zeroes you have for each number, which makes sense as those don't add anything meaningful to the interpretation of the number.